# EKS cluster on private subnet - Is it possible to access deployment's content externally without a loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I've spent about 2 days trying to figure this out and I feel like I'm getting nowhere.

If I am hosting an EKS cluster on a private subnet(s), is it possible for me to somehow access its content via an external address - without the use of a load balancer?

I've been trying to play about with an ingress-nginx controller set to use NodePort but I can't get anything to really work.